# почему значение index повторяется?

Tags: ios, swift, index, sender

Вот кусок кода.

```
 @IBAction func itemsHidden(sender: UIButton!) {
            if items.count > 0 && aiDeciding == false {
                    sender.hidden = true
                    if let index = items.indexOf(sender) {
                        items.removeAtIndex(index)
                        print("index is:",(index))
    }
    }
    }
```

Всего объектов 21-(@IBOutlet var items: [UIButton]!). 
При нажатии на объект он исчезает с экрана. Потом удаляем его индекс. Но при выводе индекса, значения повторяются.
Поясните, пожалуйста, почему так происходит?

Comment: в смысле если удалить, например, объект с индексом 10 то все равно в массиве будет объект с индексом 10?

Comment: Я беру первые три объекта. print мне вывел на втором и третьем объекте index is 4....Разве не должны они быть разными?

Comment: ааа. предположу, что после удаления 4го объекта, 5й объект сдвинулся и стал 4м, а потом и его удалили, но уже как 4й.

Comment: Ммм...скорее так и есть....Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне тогда можно присвоить уникальное значение к sender?

Comment: у UIButton есть свойство tag, можно сохранять в него (только начинайте отсчет с 1цы, потому что у всех объектов по умолчанию 0 - может получиться путаница), либо сделайте свой сабкласс UIButton и там пишите любое свойство, какое нравится

Comment: Если я удаляю через sender.tag (items.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)) идет ошибка - fatal error: Array index out of range. Я понял, что он вычитает из количества 21 не объект со знанием sender.tag, а сам sender.tag. Т.е. если я нажимаю на объект с sender.tag = 10, общее количество объектов становится 11, а не 20... Почему так?

Comment: во первых, если вам выпал объект с тэгом 21 то это сразу out of bounds - вас нет в массиве объекта с таким индексом. во вторых, по мере того как вы удаляете объекты, индекс 20 становится out of bounds, потом 19 и так далее.

Comment: после того как кнопка/объект в массиве удалены надо продолжать хранить о них информацию?

Comment: Вообще я хочу сделать, чтобы один раз за круг при нажатии на items объект не исчезал, а из тех, которые уже были взяты, появились в количестве от одного до трёх (определяется рандомно). Вот это у меня никак не получается сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Ты удаляешь объект по индексу. Сам индекс (обычный int) при этом не поменяется. 
Но функция items.indexOf(sender) выдаст уже новый результат (вроде NSNotFound) т.к. объект удален.